# Hiding a method from an assembly when referencing that assembly

Tags: assemblies

I have an assembly in which i have a method definition.
While i want to access all other methods of the assemble, i do not want to have access to this particular method in my file for the time being. Say i have been provided with a dll, i am a consumer of this dll. I want to restrict access to one of its methods in my file.
how to attain this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand corectly, depending on your assembler, you can use `EXTERN` and `PUBLIC` for procedures in different modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the reference to that function your include file (.inc) so the linker doesn't know it's there.

There's not really a good reason to do this. If you don't want to use a function, just don't call the function. It will be loaded into memory regardless.